# How to understand logistic regression cost function formula?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, loss-functions

I have found this cost function for logistic regression (source of formula:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression):

$\displaystyle \underset{w,c}{min} \ \frac{1}{2} w^{T} w+C\sum ^{n}_{i=1} log\left( exp\left( -y_{i}\left( X^{T}_{i} w+c\right)\right) +1\right)$

I would like to code this function to python, but I have some issues understanding some parts of the formula:

1. regarding this part: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} w^{T} w$

   - If *w* is vector of weights of features, how it can be transposed? Isn't that same like doing just *w * w* ?
2. regarding this part: $\displaystyle x^{T}_{i} w$

   - Here it's similar, ith vector is multiplied with another vector, so why the transpose symbol?
   - Also, most important question: if two vectors are multiplied, result is vector again. Does it mean that all 'outer' (exp, log, sum) operations are done on vectors? But in that case, function output is vector. **How do we can minimize function when output is vector?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If w is vector of weights of features, how it can be transposed? Isn't that same like doing just w * w ?

If you view a column vector as a $k \times 1$ matrix and a row vector as a $1 \times k$ matrix, then the meaning of a transpose should be obvious because it corresponds to the usual usage in linear algebra and matrix arithmetic.

The notation w * w is ambiguous. Do you mean dot product or element-wise product?

> If two vectors are multiplied, result is vector again.

This is not what the logistic cost function says. The logistic cost function uses dot products. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two vectors of length $k$. Their dot product is given by
$$
a \cdot b = a ^\top b=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i b_i = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots +a_kb_k.
$$

This result is a scalar because the products of scalars are scalars and the sums of scalars are scalars.

> Does it mean that all 'outer' (exp, log, sum) operations are done on vectors?

No, the result of a dot product is scalar.

> How do we can minimize function when output is vector?

You don't need to minimize a vector because the result of the logistic regression cost function is a scalar. You use ordinary scalar minimization.

Comment: thanks, this is clear